# The ASCII character countdown!

Tags: restricted-source, answer-chaining

Since this is a [answer-chaining](/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) challenge, you might want to sort answers by [oldest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207490/the-ascii-character-countdown?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

---

Your task is simple: Choose any printable ASCII character that's not chosen in the previous answers. And then, you need to print your chosen character in your program to standard output. (You can ONLY print your chosen character, without printing other garbage to STDOUT)

### The catch

Let's say you picked `x` as your chosen character, and your answer is the answer numbered y. You have to insert y x's into the previous source code, at any position you like. For the first answer, the previous answer is the empty program.

### An example

Answers have to start with the number 1. So for example, I chose the character `#`, and I posted a 1 byte answer in /// that prints the `#` mark.

```
#
```

And then, the second answer (numbered 2) has to insert 2 of their picked `x` character into the previous source code, such that the modified code will print their `x` character. So assume this is written in Keg:

```
x#x
```

And then, the third answer has to do the same, and so on, until 95 is reached.

### Answer format

I'd love to see an explanation of your code as well, preferably with an online interpreter link!

```
# [{Language name}]({link-to-language}), {code-length} bytes

\$y= {The number of your answer}\$. Used so far: <code>{Characters used in answers so far}</code>

    {your code}
```

### The winning criterion & other rules

- The first user whose answer stays without a succeeding answer for a month wins the challenge. If that's not satisfied, the first person who reaches the number 95 wins the challenge.
- You are not allowed to put any other character in your code other than printable ASCII characters.
- You need to wait 2 answers before you post a new answer after your submission.
- Please make sure your answer is valid. If yours is not valid, chaining answers aren't allowed to be posted.
- You can answer in a language that is used in previous answers.
- You could *only* insert y `x`'s into the source code.
- Your are not allowed to take input.
- Your program can output to STDERR, as long as the output to STDOUT is as intended.

Comment: I suggest adding a requirement to add the text "\$y=\$<answer number> Used so far: <characters used so far in order>" below the standard header (I added this to the first answer to get it going).

Comment: Can we output using our favourite language's natural output format?  For R, this would be a variable containing the particular ASCII character.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You have to output through STDOUT, unless you mention an I/O default in which setting variables is acceptable.

Comment: I posted an answer but I deleted 'cause I'm not sure it fits. The source code of the answer can only contain the previous chosen characters? e.g. I can only post `print('a')` if the characters `p,r,i,n,t,(,',)` were already chosen?

Comment: @yyyyyyyan It's stricter than that: see the very last rule. You're only allowed to insert one unique character, \$y\$ times. You can't rearrange any characters from the previous answers.

Comment: @Third-party'Chef' The current answers in 05AB1E, 2sable, and R all output a trailing newline. Also, I don't see how this is [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]? There's no fixed string or dataset to compress.

Comment: Does the program have to exit cleanly?  Or can it have an incidental error while producing the correct output?

Comment: Can we also output to stderr, if the only stdout is our character?

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter You can output to STDERR, as long as the output to STDOUT is correct.

Answer (score 8):

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 36 bytes

```
//9#999999//,#,#,221'/,#q',#q,qq2///
```

\$y=8\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/`

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f9fX99S2RIM9PV1lIHQyMhQHcgqVAdincJCI319/f//AQ)

Maybe this opens up some other languages that use `//` to comment. :)

**Explanation:**

[2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable) is an old version of [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b) (which of itself is an old version of [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E)).

The legacy version outputs a leading newline however: [try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fX99S2RIM9PV1lIHQyMhQHcgqVAdincJCI319/f//AQ).
And the latest 05AB1E version outputs three leading newline: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fX99S2RIM9PV1lIHQyMhQHcgqVAdincJCI319/f//AQ).

```python
//                                    # Divide twice, no-ops with an empty stack
  9                                   # Push 9
   #                                  # Pop and split it by spaces
                                      # (since it contains no spaces, it only pops)
    999999                            # Push 999999
          /                           # Divide the empty stack by this, popping the integer
           /                          # No-op divide again with an empty stack
            ,                         # No-op print (which would output a newline in the
                                      # newer versions)
             #,#,                     # Some more no-ops
                 221                  # Push 221
                    '/               '# Push "/"
                      ,               # Pop and print this "/" to STDOUT
                       #              # Split the 221 on spaces, so it just pops
                        q             # Exit the program
                         ',#q,qq2/// '# No-ops
```

Comment: But he waited 2 answers. He answered 5 and now 8.

Comment: @yyyyyyyan thanks, apparently counting from 5 to 8 is too much for me. I probably need to leave the counting to my two-year-old.

Comment: @Giuseppe yyyyyyyan is indeed correct, there are 2 answers in between. I actually already have a plan to add some more answers (if the two characters I need are still available by then) for when it's my turn again. ;) Although I'm going on vacation starting tomorrow for a week, and I'm not sure I have wifi (or whether I'm in the mood for codegolf) over there, so I doubt I'm able to add the two I had planned.

Answer (score 7):

## Polyglot, 3 bytes

```
1''
```

\$y=2\$. Used thus far: `1'`.

This works in a bunch of stack-based languages, which basically all do the following:

```python
1    # Push a 1 to the stack
 ''  # Push the string "'" to the stack
     # (output the top of the stack implicitly as result)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S87PzU0sSfz/31Bd/f9/AA) in [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Commands).
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fUF39/38A) in [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands).
[Try it online](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=MScn) in [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt).
etc.

> *Tip: Using a similar stack-based language, it's easy to insert almost any character by interleaving.*

Comment: It's possible?!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

\$y=4\$. Used so far: `1'2q`

```
221'q'qqq2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyMhQvVC9sLDQ6P9/AA)

```ruby
221         # push 221 to the stack 
   'q'q     # push character q (twice for good measure)
       q    # quit; implicitly print top-of-stack q
        q2  # no-ops
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 bytes

```
###221'#q'#qqq2
```

\$y=5\$. Used thus far: `1'2q#`

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fWVnZyMhQXbkQiAoLjf7/BwA)

Maybe this opens up some other languages that use `#` to comment. :)

**Explanation:**

```python
###              # Split by spaces three times (no-ops without input)
   221           # Push integer 221
      '#        '# Push character "#"
        q        # Stop the program
                 # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
         '#qqq2 '# No-ops
```

Comment: Thank-you from one of the '# to comment' language-users!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 21 bytes

```
#,#,#,221',#q',#q,qq2
```

\$y=6\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X1kHBI2MDNV1lAtBWKew0Oj/fwA)

```
#                         # Skip the next instruction
 ,                        # (skipped)
  #,                      # (skipped)
    #,                    # (skipped)
      221                 # Push 2, 2, 1 onto the stack
         ',               # Push character ','
           #q             # (skipped by #)
             ',           # Push character ','
               #q         # (skipped)
                 ,        # Output character
                  q       # Quit program
                   q2     # (not executed)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 45 bytes

\$y=9\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j`

```
//9#999999//j,#,#,221'j/,#qjjjjj'j,#jq,qq2///
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz///X17dUtgQDff0sHWUgNDIyVM/S11EuzAIBdaBgVqFOYaGRvr7@//8A)

#### Explanation

Mainly (ab)uses `j` to skip sections we don't want to execute.

```
//                                              # Divide twice (no-ops, as 0/0 is 0 in Befunge-98)
  9                                             # Push 9
   #9                                           # No-op (skipped by #)
     99999                                      # Push more 9s
          /                                     # Divide, results in 9/9 = 1
           /                                    # Divide, results in 9/1 = 9
            j                                   # Jump forward 9 instructions
             ,#,#,221'                          # (not executed)
                      j                         # Jump forward 9 instructions
                       /,#qjjjjj                # (not executed)
                                'j              # Push the character 'j'
                                  ,             # Print the character
                                   #j           # No-op
                                     q          # Quit program
                                      ,qq2///   # (not executed)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 55 bytes

\$y=10\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\`

```
\//9#9\99999//j,\\\#,#,221'j/\,#\\qjjjjj'j,#\jq,qq2/\//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcshDsAwDATBxxiEnHSqmf9ytIpq5qj/d5JBS/Zf35zv6hYZFoqLTEgyGNyfkRRMqrxGns5ClfM83Rs)

This took a lot longer than I'm willing to admit...

Comment: explanation is in the works... (I'll finish it in the morning)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
9#999999,#,#,221',#q',#q,qq2
```

\$y=7\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/31LZEgx0lIHQyMhQXUe5EIR1CguN/v8HAA)

Based on a combination of [functions may output via their return values](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/2456?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C106.8617#2456) and the fact that R functions naturally output their return values to STDOUT (albeit with some prepended characters to indicate index of the outputed value), I hope that this is Ok.

Explanation:

```r
9               # integer value 9; output by default
 #              # comment character; everything after this (on the same line) is ignored
  999999,#,#,221',#q',#q,qq2
                # not run
```

Big thank-you to Kevin Cruijssen for putting the `#` character at the beginning of answer #5, which (as he suspected) was critical to make this answer work!

Answer (score 5):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 66 bytes

\$y=11\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;`

```
;\//9#9\99999//j,\\\#,#,221;';;j/\;,;#\\;qjjjjj'j,#\jq,qq2/\//;;;;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxCoAwDAXQw2ToEgl2Mvyr/EmoQoZCBs8f27e/ezzffMfhVxVo5uL0zSyUpKho7ycaEEYohETG1kKFkZrZbU0sVT8)

`;` is the comment character in Befunge, and this program works by running `';,q` with inapplicable parts commented out. Doesn't work in Pyfunge for reasons I can't figure out.

Answer (score 5):

## [Befunge-98](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98), 253 bytes

\$y=22\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%7*x`

```
*7%7*77%*7*77%666666%x*77*7%*7*77%6*666666666655555555555555444444%***4%44*4*444444xxxx"033333%33333333s;s\/s/90*%35*s46#"9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,\"\*0\"#s,#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/x\xxxx"s;xxx,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q2/"\%s//s;0;%;;0"s77*77777xxxxxx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc9RCsMgDADQu0RCIVjMWlsnXsWvQTfIx1gJA3d6Z2UU9gIhCSbgbbu/n49tjNfx9ellrRQwUAhIPa8dllbTOaP1tPzxHRKRR@@pRVca4PmA848mzU5dZMJ5IfWrgZg1RsSIkTU6cMJqM2TiDEatsdOkfElAgwIlTuJK7pc1tWw5oSnteWt2FRJgQRQZxJoMgrvanffJQUZ1Tts@psSgx78Opav1Cw)

After running the part before the first `x`, the top of the stack is `6 0` (from the code `666%`). Thus, the `x` instruction sets the *program delta* to (6, 0), meaning that the instruction pointer moves right 6 spaces every step. This skips over most of the remaining instructions, leaving `%%66554*44"33s0s\9/,\,;*x",\q0'j0%0"7x` to be executed. `%%66544*44` does some stack manipulation, `"33s0s\9/,\,;*x"` pushes the string `x*;,\,/9\s0s33`, and `,` prints the first character of that string, which is `x`. Finally, `\` swaps the top two elements of the stack (which we don't care about) and `q` ends the program.

Answer (score 4):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 1 byte

\$y=1\$ Used so far: `1`

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/3/D/fwA)

Just to start things off.

**Explanation:**

```
1     # since this isn't a / or \, the character is simply printed and removed.  
      # no characters left so the program terminates.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

\$y=3\$ Used so far: `1'2`

```
221''2
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=MjIxJycy)

### Explanation

The code is transpiled to `221, "'", 2` and Japt only implicitly prints the last expression so outputs 2

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`, 78 bytes

\$y=12\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0`

```
0;\//90#9\999909//j0,\\0\#,#,2201;';0;j/\;,0;#\\;qjj0jjj'j,#\jq,q0q2/\//;0;;;0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcwxDsMwDEPRw2jwokKMN4NX4RokYCf3/oDqPz/87/10g6paiKV1wqoyUoIiI@fExUHQJSYYErcN28MZ8s6NPessDiLR3Z/39wc)

And this kids, is why we use languages where single digits auto push! This pushes a whole bunch of stuff, a 0, then prints the t.o.s using the `-hr` flag.

Answer (score 4):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 190 bytes

\$y=19\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%`

```
%%%666666%%%6666666666655555555555555444444%4%444444444"033333%33333333s;s\/s/90%35s46#"9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,\"\0\"#s,#,22s01;"'s";0;j/\"s;,0;%#\"\;qsjj"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q2/"\%s//s;0;%;;0"s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctLCsMwDATQu8gM2Rik5gdGV/G2hGrnTO/vuqEt9M1GDKPn@TiO@9k7gP3yOy7bn/WCkS@x5Q3LB51VqcWwbFz3JKWyFKCgGIuKhjFXqVYlMac8z7Sby0Rx89Aq9GyONCbeGCEWQMQUeVSBxtyszSoVVOX4gbsJe38B)

Here's hoping using `%` makes a lot of languages a lot harder to use

Comment: `%` is no issue for me.  However starting your answer with 3 of the same character is.

Answer (score 4):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 276 bytes

\$y=23\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%7*x@`

```
@@@*@@@@@@@@7%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*77*7%*7*7@7%6*@666666666655555555555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx"033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#"9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,\"\*0\"#s,#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x\xxxx"s;x@xx,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q2/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s77*77777@xxxxxx@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc/NasMwDADgd5ERBWGwlrgJRhc9iK@lVLdUO@jtM8crg30Cg4R@8Pf79Xw@3uepqqQfO@6070jz3SbUGAn9FkfDRrr9uf9TJyQlqlgrjZgiNAJ4veD64eK9uJbGhOudvG4JWvfWEBs29lagGHvu0Ik7JM8pL4vzlwDdHEhYrGj0GMDlOpFZMMUYkIjDjQzYEM1ullMHw8PzwcdSoOM4XHysQBEGv/530ZhUz/MH)

Hopefully `@` makes even more languages harder to use.... looking at you Befunge-98

Answer (score 4):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 351 bytes

\$y=26\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%7*x@f8.`

```
...ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.6655555555555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.\"\*0\"#s,#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.7777@xxxxxx@@..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc/BagQhDAbgd8kQFoLEdHZ2HPGSB/HaLvU2mx7y9lNHhtLST/hRowa/Xp/P5/vrOJj548ev6Vhup3/ZQ1mV9JIYE6WENHIdUJ1SP8lb3zwrnLTXSNcLr@vjj2VAUqIFl4X6GNzVHVjuJ7xfrFiNpjEL4f1BtqwTcK6WM2LGLJYjxCYWuEIlqTBZmMI8m7wVoJsBFSktqnNl78DK2Yc5SMHJ@6XivlujBtIQW7u1MFVouFvYZZ@3CBV7/2j9HSxFwDj1r/ZISX1QZT6Obw)

We're out of digits now, that should make things a little more interesting. I think we've made every language other than Trigger unusable at this point...

Answer (score 4):

## HTML, 630 bytes

\$y = 35\$, Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb=cd< ``

````````````````````````html
<<dddcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdc==d=b=b=b=`HH&&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".==033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`\`ccdc"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.========================7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
````````````````````````

Save as `index.html` and run with `w3m -dump index.html`, so it goes to stdout as expected.

`<dd....` is an un-closed html tag, which rendered into nothing. So the first `<` character rendered as HTML content.

[w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) is an old school browser which use text I/O to render HTML. As this question is requiring stdout output. I'm also surprised that w3m may successfully parse and render such a malformed HTML.

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`, 105 bytes

\$y=14\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"3`

```
"03333333333333;\//903#"9\999909/"/j0,\"\0\"#,#,2201;"'";0;j/\";,0;#\"\;qjj"0jjj'j,#\"jq,q0q2/"\//;0;;;0"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDsMwDAP/Qg9ZVIh1JkNf0Vo0YCfn/4CisbcRR9zv860Cz38i3RfPgZWr4XK4aIlkYtiwOfkOHAiGPBHGGG1jS6CkQ9Zb2zb3dHSunxFEVb2u@wE) or [Check it!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDgIxDAR7nrEp0ljyXlJF/gINokNuOOkK3KDofsRT@FhwyXSjHe37fO6vY63z/v08rre1wP6PuepgLxg@Eg6FBsXhdBQp0ho3Q4XRQh0mtJKrzQgwImpIekyZnE2Rd1maEZettllkaHha/wE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 231 bytes

\$y=21\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%7*`

```
*7%7*77%*7*77%666666%*77*7%*7*77%6*666666666655555555555555444444%***4%44*4*444444"033333%33333333s;s\/s/90*%35*s46#"9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,\"\*0\"#s,#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/\"s;,0;%#\"\;qsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q2/"\%s//s;0;%;;0"s77*77777
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc/BCsMwCAbgdzFIQQK6NmsIvkquo8xb6t4/S8M22CcI/ujB1/k8jsfZO2XMlDPS7Ps0hjF9I9p/7n/ShESUMCUaNYFsF9w@XL2ycxHC7U6e9gCleimIBYt4YWATjxUqSYXgMcR1dbkp0OJAKmpcwTWKYhhb2tzIQAzRbLE4MsPmsUlbGSo6s48jVBXw65FL728)

This language is really weird. I got this working by pure luck after about an hour

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`, 325 bytes

\$y=25\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%7*x@f8`

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffff888888888888888888888@@@*@@@@@@@@7%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78887*7%*7*7@7%6*@666666666655555555555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx"033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#"9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,\"\*0\"#s,#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x\xxxx"s;x@xx,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s77*77777@xxxxxx@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/NigMhDADgd4mEQrCYztix4iUP4rXdxT1Nc8nbW0fKwsL2C@QQ8kN@7l@9Pz64/UdESN4SJkoJaeZtQjFKo22UZn30bCTbr@sfcUISoogx0ojJTMyA1wOub1q0BpWQmXC9ksbNQa6aM2LGzJoDhMbqK1TiCk6988uifClAJwUqXFoQqzaAluOE54LOxkAx27VRA26IrZ2adxUa7up33pdbgIrjctCxA0th0HT8PIhNIr338/fzBQ)

(no explanation because I have no idea how Keg works)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 91 bytes

\$y=13\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"`

```
"0;\//90#"9\999909/"/j0,\"\0\"#,#,2201;"'";0;j/\";,0;#\"\;qjj"0jjj'j,#\"jq,q0q2/"\//;0;;;0"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYwhDsQwEAP/4oCSldYNi/yVJaVmUQ/c79M1G83I7@/5nwOqMhcHVq0eVyLNKBQLI0bMyVu4IMpZUFCjrbYN2r4czd6xuWei37qUiHM@)

I know that OPs aren't intended to answer their own questions, but after seeing that nobody has the enthusiasm to add the quote character...

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 136 bytes

\$y = 16\$, Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s`

```
55555555555555"03333333333333s;s\/s/9035s#"9\s99990s9/"/j0s,\"\0\"#s,#,22s01;"'s";0;j/\"s;,0;#\"\;qsjj"0jjj'j,#\"jqs,q0q2/"\s//s;0;;;0"s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcohDsQwDETRu0xAiSXPpiqIfBWTpWbRFOzts4Htg19f9/e31vUCnk8KpcsHz0sNIzU2aji8KEskE03WrHfxEziEYJQnFMZo@4ipKrCqjrIdasomZ3ek3LX3CEJr/QE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-hr`, 153 bytes

\$y = 17\$, Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s4`

```
555555555555554444444444444444"03333333333333s;s\/s/9035s4#"9\s99990s9/"/j0s,\"\0\"#s,#,22s01;"'s";0;j/\"s;,0;#\"\;qsjj"0jjj'j,#\"jqs,q0q2/"\s//s;0;;;0"s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcoxDgIxDETRu0yKbYxssrtF5Ku4XYFMFeb@MimBV3791/WoOn8cf2D7NzpDqcP2k0fDCI7FOBSaRgmEBRqlSe@0u2Mj3Dw1QBfztg6fzIRl5payQk7KtNkVQVWu3d3Aqro93x8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), - hr, 171 bytes

\$y=18\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46`

```
66666666666666666555555555555554444444444444444"03333333333333s;s\/s/9035s46#"9\s99990s9/"/j0s,\"\0\"#s,#,22s01;"'s";0;j/\"s;,0;#\"\;qsjj"0jjj'j,#\"jqs,q0q2/"\s//s;0;;;0"s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xco7DsMwDATRu1CFGwbcyB9A4FXYBgnoSt77Q1GZ@JWDOV/vMY67/c92I1h/0RlGa1h3bkeRFmwT2EwsQQ0JhBRq0VqJp8tCcXhaCF3hZR7emSnIzCV1huzUjl5NgmacuzuEY4zH5/oC)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 210 bytes

\$y=20\$. Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%7`

```matlab
7%777%777%666666%777%777%6666666666655555555555555444444%4%444444444"033333%33333333s;s\/s/90%35s46#"9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,\"\0\"#s,#,22s01;"'s";0;j/\"s;,0;%#\"\;qsjj"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q2/"\%s//s;0;%;;0"s7777777
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XctNCgIxDAXgu6SE2RQS58dScpVsRNxkI@WJ1691Rhf6PbJIeLlfH5fnrffCpRxz3v2tu@3HuuORL9LljZcPGFwgVXnZsJ4TVUetzJWrogpJKLKTq1NCTnmeoSejCWRqIU6wrMZpVKwhgjSYI6bI4xTckJu2WcgZIhg/bKaEcuj9BQ)

Except for MATLAB/Octave, you mean?

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hd`,  300 bytes

\$y=24\$ Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%7*x@f`

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffff@@@*@@@@@@@@7%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*77*7%*7*7@7%6*@666666666655555555555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx"033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#"9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,\"\*0\"#s,#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x\xxxx"s;x@xx,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q2/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s77*77777@xxxxxx@@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc9LasQwDADQu8iIAeFiNfEkGG10EC87H9xV0Ea39zjuUOiiT2CQ0Ad/3x693/@hqqRvO@6070jz3SZUHwn9FEfDRrr9uv6RJyQlypgzjZjc1R14PeH6ZmI1mabChOuVLG8BSrVSEAsWtpIgNbZYoRJXCBZDXBbjTwG6GJCwtKRefQCT80RkweBjQNwPa9SAG2JrlxZDhYaHxYOPJUHFcTjZWIEiDHb@76Q@qfbeP55fLw)

Harder? It actually made it easier. `@` starts a function in Keg, and because there aren't any closing `ƒ`s (and there won't be because it ain't ascii), everything after the first `@` is ignored. What a clanger!

Answer (score 2):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 378 bytes

\$y = 27\$, Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`

```
aaa.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.6655555555555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.\"\*0\"#s,#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.7777@xxxxxx@@..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/BasQgEAbgd5kwLAwyTpNsjHiZB/GSQ7vUW3Z68O2zRkJpKf2EH3XUwa/n5@Px/jyObdt4@wfzx7cf075cT3@yhbIq6SUwBgoBqefSoVYK7SSvbfOscNBWI10uvCz3X@YOSYlmnGdqo6tVawWW6YTTxZJlb@qjEE53snkZgGO2GBEjRrHowRcxxxkySYbB3ODG0eQtAd0MKEkqXitnrg1YOvswO0k41HYp1bpboQJSEEu5FTdkKLib22UfVw8ZW39v7R1MScA4tK@2CEFrp8p8HC8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rn`, 406 bytes

\$y=28\$, `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a` ``

````````````````````````
`aaa.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.6655555555555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`\`"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/dasUgDAfwd0kJB4KLru2pFW/yIF7Yi23gYNCTG9@@s1LGxraf8EdN8OP95e048rZtvP2D@fXLt2lfrqdf2UJYhOTiGT15j9Rz6VAq@dbJa9s8K@yl1UiWCy/L/Ye5QxKiGeeZ2uhqlVqB3XTC6aJRk1WxwRFOd9J5GYBD0hAQAwanwYItTg3nlCEncgkGNXkw46juOQLdFCi6WKxUTlwb0HjexWxcxKEmSLHWXQsVcAWxlFsxQ4KCu5rd7eNqIWF7g9V2DsboQNm377bwXmonwpz/dhzH0@PjEw)

Hehe. I used the power of strings to essentially make those `.`s nops.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 465 bytes

\$y=30\$, Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&H ``

````````````````````````
`HH&&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.6655555555HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`\`"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDBasQgEAbgd5kwWRjCaJNsjHiZYx7CQ/aybaWwhLn49qmxoRS67af8qCMqvj4@7u/6tu/rsrRtezt6CW6fuf2B@f7tx7BO58OvLCEsQnJyjI6cQ6o5VSiZXNnJc1k8Kuyk1EimE0/T9bT842vHWCEJ0YjjSKVVOUvOwHY44HDSoNGoGG8JhyvpODXAPqr3iB69VW/AJKsdr3GFNZKN0Gi3Nl3fq30JQBcFCjYkI5kj5wI0HHcxdzZgkyPEkPOmiRLYhJjSJXVNhISbdpvd@tlAxPIGo@UcDMGCsitfUcI5yZUI8/rcvn8C)

### Explanation

```
`   Push codepoint of next character:
 H  'H'
  H Halt, printing TOS as a character
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 496 bytes

\$y=31\$, Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb ``

````````````````````````
bbb`HH&&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`\`"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddDBasQgEAbgd5kwWRjCaHeTGPEyxzyEh2ygXeotOz349qmxSyl091N@1BEVv@6ft9v7fd/XdV3muW3b69FLcPvM9QXmj19/hnU6Hf5lCWERkgfH6Mg5pJpjhZLJlZ08lcWjwk5KjWR84HEcqnUY5nmdX/rZ1VdIQtRj31NpVc6SM7C9HPDyoEGjUTHeEl4G0n5sgH1U7xE9eqvegElWO17iAkskG6HRbmm681ntWwA6KVCwIRnJHDkXoOG4i7mzAZscIYacN02UwCbElE6payIk3LTb7HaeDEQsbzBazsEQLCi78hklnJNciTAvz60v7fs3)

Answer (score 2):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 528 bytes

\$y=32\$, Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb= ``

````````````````````````
===b=b=b=`HH&&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".==033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`\`"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.========================7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBRa8QgDADg/2JJD0KJ7q6tFSnksT/Ch15hO@ZbL3vw33fWHWOw9osENUHFr@fn4/H@3LZxHJcS8zTVdX3fR05UH7mfIPr49WdalsPuX86JiRn5xRJYtBaw5L4ATmhzJw15c6@Q5VxD7l@o77ti6bppWqZTP11tAciILbQt5ihS4pQUjaO57eD2Il6CFtbOINw6lLavFLkgzgE4cEacVjoaaWgOs5oDmqAqaeaquV7FvHmFF1HojY@aEwVKmRK/30bUGA9VCir4lFaJGJWJADFeYlMFFWGVZjXrddAqQH6DlnwOeG@UkM3fkV97zGacCmai@dhyatu@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Explode](https://github.com/stestoltz/Explode), 741 bytes

\$y=38\$. Used thus far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb=cd<AB ``  (trailing space)

````````````````````````
AAB<<dddcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdc==d=b=b=b=`HH&AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%6AAAB66666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".==033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`AB\`ABccdcAAAAAAAB"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.========================7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB                                      B
````````````````````````

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jdBRa4MwEADgvzIiZ@GQM2vVVFIh@uSPyIO1dg9hsMm95N@7xHVjMNvtS3IkXEiOu/r317fpuixt251O0zRdHpkuTTM14zqGvk/bTV2anuMMgdIt5zuIXr792K7HY/QrhmDIGDQ3ikChUoBrrGIxVQTGowq36RgSMUvKhDya6oaqqlyNZdn3Y3/X561iBWgQCygKDGPlvfFeUNPIQwSHG9ZsczZ5LREOJXJRJYJqy3UNUEMtuc5F7iRnNLSdDSv2@qudYrAorUg4G5Jsv2f5rAXuWKCW2uXGkyUfCNbxd6JMaki8FVZ7P7NDJ6QDcG7nssQKBzNns5z3x1xYCDXlHN4BraVgUqE9ofptKjB@ZQzRsG28a3rg9Jfuoad/6ZblAw)

**Explanation:**

I just went looking for some random languages that might work, to have something different than Keg and Trigger in the chain. I had never heard about Explode prior, but apparently the tape starts with the amount of spaces equal to the number of lines of the program; which is a single line, thus a single space in this case.
This tape is printed implicitly when the program terminates. Since the program (apparently) doesn't modify the tape in any way, this single space the tape started with is output as our result.

I might try to analyze what each character actually does in the program above, or try to use the language Explode for another challenge, but this will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`, 120 bytes

\$y = 15\$, Used so far: `1'2q#,9/j\;0"35`

```
55555555555555"03333333333333;\//9035#"9\999909/"/j0,\"\0\"#,#,2201;"'";0;j/\";,0;#\"\;qjj"0jjj'j,#\"jq,q0q2/"\//;0;;;0"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcwxDgJBDAPAv3iLa4Ji9nTFKl9Ji0CmWv4vhZQwnWXL78ez6voDnr8i3RfPa2DlalwOFy2RTAwbNifvgQPBkCfCGKPb2BIo6ZB11rbNPR3918sIoqpur88X)

Yeah, you can pretty much tell that I'm gonna do this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 435 bytes

\$y = 29\$, Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`& ``

````````````````````````
`&&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.6655555555555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`\`"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/NbsMgDAfwd3HkVLIiw5I0BHHxg3Cgh60at9Q98PYZQdG0ad0P9BdgxMfz8Xm/vz/2PfV9fzt6De5fuf2D@ePbj2Gbroc/WUNYhOTkGB05h9RyaVAKubqT17p4VNhJrZEsJ16W6y9zgyREM84z1daUIqUA2@mA00mDRqNivCWcrqTz0gH7qN4jevRWvQGTrQ6cYoIUyUbodEjdMI5q3wLQRYGCDdlI4cilAg3HXcyDDdiVCDGUsmmmDDYj5nzJQxch46bDZrdxNRCxvsFoPQdDsKDs6ndrOCelEWFOr@37Fw)

It seriously looks like Trigger and Keg are the only viable choices now.
The second-twelfth bytes do the magic; it jumps to the second ".", so I could hide my ampersands.

Also, it looks like the "used so far" bit is broken now.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf.SE, nice first answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 595 bytes

\$y = 34\$, Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb=c ``

````````````````````````
dddcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdc==d=b=b=b=`HH&&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".==033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`\`ccdc"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.========================7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBRa8MgEADg/2K4FI5wcW0SIxK4x/wIH9I0W5lv6e3Bf58ZV8Zgbb@TQ71Dxa/b5/X6ftu2ZVkuryyXYViGOcc0jmVZnveREpWPnJ8g@vj1Z5qX/e5fTomJGfnOEBg0BjDnLgOOaFIn9Wlzr5DhVEPu7qjr2mxu23Gcx6d@upoMkBEbaBpMkcXIMSoaBn3awelOnPhauLYa4dSiNF2hyHqxFsCC1WJrVQctFU1@2j9TTR61V4VUU1Edj6LfnMKDKHTahZojeYqJErffSFRpB0X0yrsYVwkYlA4AIRxCVXgVYJVq1euxr5WH9I5a0jngnFZCJn1JevFjJuGYMRNNj81PLS9s2zc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-rn`, 703 bytes

\$y=37\$, Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb=cd<AB ``

````````````````````````
AAB<<dddcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdc==d=b=b=b=`HH&AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%6AAAB66666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".==033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`AB\`ABccdcAAAAAAAB"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.========================7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdBRa4MwEADg/xI5C4c7s1ZNJRWiT/6IPFhrN8hg4O4l/94lrhuD2e5LciRcSI57u74uS9t2p9M0TZdHpkvTTM24jqHv03ZTl6bnOEOgdMv5DqKXH7@26/EY/YkhGDIGzY0iUKgU4BqrWEwVgfGowm06hkTMkjIhj6a6oaoqV2NZ9v3Y3/V1q1gBGsQCigLDWHlvvBfUNPIQweGGNducTV5LhEOJXFSJoNpyXQPUUEuuc5E7yRkNbWfDir3@bqcYLEorEs6GJNvvWT5rgTsWqKV2ufFkyQeCdfydKJMaEm@F1d7P7NAJ6QCc27ksscLBzNks5/0xFxZCTTmHd0BrKZhUaE@ofpsKjF8ZQzRsG@@aHjj9p3tsWZanj/dP)

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rn`, 561 bytes

\$y=33\$, Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb=c ``

````````````````````````
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc===b=b=b=`HH&&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%666666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".==033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`\`ccc"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.========================7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBRa8QgDADg/2JJD0IXXa@tJ1LIY3@ED72O7cDBoMuL/76z7hiDXfdFgpqg4vvrbdte/jWO41Jinqa6rq/7yInqR64HiN5@/JqW5WX3J@fExIx8ZwksWgtY8lAAJ7S5ky55c6@Q5VxDHu5oGPpi6ftpWqZD311dAciIHXQd5ihS4pQUjaM57@B8J16CFtbOIJx7lG6oFLkgzgE4cEacVjoaaWgOc/5KNQc0QVXSzFXTtmKevcKTKPTGR82JAqVMid8vJGqMhyoFFXxKq0SMykSAGE@xqYKKsEqzmrW9aBUgP0NLPge8N0rI5h/JD37MZpwKZqL5seXQtm1Pnx9f)

;P

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-rn`, 666 bytes

\$y=36\$ , Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb=cd<A ``

````````````````````````
AA<<dddcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdc==d=b=b=b=`HH&AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&&a&&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%6AAA66666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%44*4*444444xx@xx".==033333%33333333s;s\/s@/90*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%90s9/"/j0s,.`A\`AccdcAAAAAAA"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxqsj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.========================7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdBRa8MgEADg/2K4FI7sdG0SG2zAvOVH@JCm2QYOBtm9@O8z48IYLO0@5VBP9Lj3l7dl6brLZZqm2yPTrW2ndkxj6Pu825Xn13XGQPme6x1Erz9@LdP2vPoTY7BkLdqNJtCoNWCKdaylXoENqONlOsfzNUnaxjTaekN1XSVjVfX92N/1fatMAC1iCWWJcSQh2BAEta06reC0YcNOspWNQjhVyGWdCWocNw1AA43iRgrpFRc0dG7o1j5vrRSDQ@VExsWQFccjq2cj8MACjTJe2kCOQiTYrF8TFcpAFpxwJoSZPXqhPID3B19kTniYuZjVfDxL4SAWJDm@A8YowaRjb2Lp@3RkQ2It0bBvvGt64PKfZVmePj@@AA)

Yet another one. Just like the other one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 780 bytes

\$y=39\$. Used thus far: `` 1'2q#,9/j;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb=cd<AB _ ``

````````````````````````
__AAB<<dddccccccccc___ccccccccccccccccccccdc==d=b=b=b=`HH&_AAAAAAAAA_AAAAAAAA_AAAAAB&&a&_&a&a&&.&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&aaaaaaaaaa__aaaaaaaaa__aaaaa..ffffffffff.ffffffffffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%6AA__AB66666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH555555444444%*@**4%4_4*4*444444xx@xx".==033333%33333333s;s\/s@/9_________0*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%____90s9/_____"/j0s,.`AB\`ABccdcAAAAAAAB"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxq__sj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@_//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.========================7777@xxxxxx@@..```````````````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbdddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<<<<<<<<<<<<__<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB                                      B
````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdFRb4MgEADgv7JgsAkxJ2tVatCE@uSPIDlr3ZrxZtkD/94hs0232WYf4XLmDgL4efk4n98u04R4ODRVNQzD6QoRTyuGU10PdR9G17axX7jAn0kTx8cY/TzGMcRrjjeIv1OA95u7NHzuZ3@iDwqUYmohgAomBGUhFv5YeGiKGVWOCd8Pe1@a6yCU72CqWEBR5EGf523btw99d2UBZYqxjGaYMT8C55RzBOqa72Z0t7DS6tSqtMQrzuguZzYrIgKltmVJaUnnQsltmYYWkhpuE@gOjfZz/hHLczek04xrEtmki5Lt1vJXSdjGEia5NKlyoMF5xMr5PAAJlzRymmjp3IhoDTOEG0qN2Zgk0sTQ0SYjH7f7lGhqFaap9VtRKTmxIPyj@SutE55ygVIA3br@oeGJ6g5itaZ56uVfmmn6Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 820 bytes

\$y=40\$. Used so far: `` 1'2q#,9/j\;0"35s46%7*x@f8.a`&Hb=cd<AB _z ``.
(I have restored `\`, which disappeared from this string earlier in the thread.)

```````````````
zzz_z_AAzB<<ddzdcccczccccc__z_cccccccczccccccccccccdc==d=b=b=b=`HH&_AAAAzAAAAA_AAAAzAAAA_AAAAAB&&a&_&a&a&&.&&&&z&&&&&z&&&&&z&&&&&&&aaaazaaaaaa__aaaazaaaaa__aaaaa..fffffzfffff.ffffzffffzffffff.88888.88888.88888.8888.88@.@@*@@@@@@@@7.%7*77%*7*77%z6AA__zAB66666%@x*78.8.87*7%*7*.7@7%6*@66666666.66555555b55HHbHHHHHHzHHHHHHHzHHHHHHHHHzHHHH555555444444%*@**4%4_4*4*444444xx@xx".==033333%3333z3333s;s\/s@/9____z_____0*%35*s46#".9\s99%%9%____90s9/_____"/j0s,.`AB\`ABccdcAAzAAAAAB"`\*0\"#s,`#,22s01;"*'s"*;0;j/@x.\.xxxx"s;x@xx..,0;%#x\"\;xxq__sj*j"0j%%jj'j,#\"j%qs,q0q28/"\%s@_//s;0;%;;0"s.77*7.========z================7777@xxxxxx@@..`````````z``````````````bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbzbbbddddzddddddddddddddddzdddddddd<<<<<<z<<<<<<__<<<<<<<<<z<<<<<<<<<<<<zBBBBBBBBBBBBzBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB                                      zzBzz
```````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdLRjqMgFAbgV9lgcBJijmzHSo2aoFc@BAm2OjNZ7jrsBTkv3z1gO9N292I/w@9BwSD6@/PXx8fb5@WCiBbtMODYdeuK60IwxmLp@nKFy5116fu1P6VjnqacZtP8GMN3maphzPNjbqkd8xxygvlz0giCx8Ta785WHwHeI0wJX@XWf4dD9FdSaNBa6CsFXAmluEiJNa3P4jDWEddBKJoBB7oZR4DSitdC11dQ1/vktN9P02lKcHo8X6ttYJVwoYWoeGUrQUcSgg6BQd/L14jHwBi@9ab0umysjfseScFf98JXdcagMb5pOG94vNFI35RpCCud9AXMw2ioxS9z@xAjm42QhmW@mLNit/PyZ8vEi2eila0rdQADgTDfxiUBFLLlWTDMtCGcrfVOOCYd5869uCIzzPGzL87yvDuUzHCvbVl6ehRvW8k8KNo6eqsN9k8U0SHRGmC@wfnB6d@Q2rrGf/PJ14Uuwe1kbXeD3R0c7zx0Nj/@C@KIeLn8AQ)

The previous answer has stood unchallenged for three weeks so it's time to spoil the party. The first three characters really sum up how I feel about the inventiveness of the present submission. It's perfectly set up for a `FizzBuzz` finish, however.